# What do I do when a Long isn't long enough (Java)?

Tags: java, variables

So, I'm working through the bottom of Project Euler.  There are a lot of great problems there (most of which are way above my level).  But I very quickly came across a major problem:

Java will not do huge numbers.

Now, if I had the ability to make fast programs taking alternative routes, this would not be a problem for me.  Unfortunately, I am not that person.

Take, for example, Problem 20.  It call to find the digit sum of 100!  I wasn't even writing for the digit parsing, but just my code to find the factorial failed.

```
long onehfact = 1;
for(int i = 1; i <= 100; i++){
    onehfact = onehfact * i;
    System.out.println(onehfact);
}
```

This worked for about 20 sequences, but started giving random-ish 19 digit numbers.  By 75 sequences, it was just giving me zero.

`100!` is definitely not zero.

I need a way to have incredibly large numbers, and scientific notation will not work for my purposes.  Is there a large variable type that I could use, that can hold numbers as large as 100-150 digits?  Is there any other solution that would have the same result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [BigInteger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) to satisfy your requirement.

```
BigInteger onehfact = BigInteger.valueOf(1L);
for(long i = 1; i <= 100; i++){
    onehfact = onehfact.multiply(i);    
    System.out.println(onehfact);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

There is a class called BigInteger that will allow you to handle and perform operations on numbers of any size.  It will allocate a variable amount of memory for the digits.

Here is the documentation.  The class is in the `java.math` package:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html

I worked through some problems in Project Euler in Java, too.  For some of the other problems you are dealing with large non-integer numbers and you need the related class `java.math.BigDecimal`:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html

Comment: Wouldn't that have catastrophic affects if, say, your for loop never ended or had a break; statement

Comment: Java has garbage collection and can throw a StackOverflowException if the memory is used up, so worst case, it won't be that bad.